# Отделяется ли запятой союз НО

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> *Но() если тебе интересно, могу рассказать.*

Отделяется ли запятой "но"? Объясните, по какому правилу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Лопатина:

> 3. В начале предложения не разделяются запятой сочинительный и подчинительный союзы, а также подчинительный союз и союзное слово:
>      Денис помер. И когда я уезжал, старуха его вынесла мне гуся...
>      (Пришв.); И прости, и уже навсегда, навеки... Потому что где же они
>      теперь могут встретиться? (Бун.).

https://orfhographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg123.php

У Розенталя:

> 5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом (в начале предложения, после точки) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом
>      зависит от значения союза:
>
> 1) как правило, после союза ***и*** запятая не ставится: И когда Левинсон,
>   выполнив все будничные дела, отдал наконец приказ выступать, — в
>   отряде наступило такое ликование, точно с этим приказом на самом деле
>   кончались всякие мытарства (Ф.); И хотя погода значительно улучшилась,
>   опасность засухи не миновала; И вместо того чтобы свернуть направо, по
>   ошибке поехали прямо;
>
> 2) после присоединительного союза ***а*** запятая не ставится: А когда
>   взошло солнце, перед нами открылся вид на снеговую вершину; А если
>   верить сообщениям синоптиков, завтра должно наступить потепление;
>
> 3) после союза ***но*** запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и
>   не ставится, если паузы нет; ср.: Но, если далее противнику удавалось
>   отбить атакующих, пехота снова бросалась в атаку (Сим.); Но когда он,
>   опираясь на палку, вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… и, не
>   ожидая, пока его обнимут, сам стал обнимать и целовать всех, кто
>   попадал в его объятия, что-то защемило в ране (Павл.);
>
> 4) после союза ***однако*** запятая обычно ставится: Однако, если
>   обстоятельства того потребуют, я в стороне стоять не буду.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140

Так что лучше не ставить - это обычный случай. Если же автор при произнесении сделает паузу и отнесёт союз к главному предложению, то он может поставить, ошибкой не будет, как утверждает Розенталь (пункт 3).